# django commands gets stuck when I run makemigrations or createsuperuser etc

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have a Django application, and when I run `python manage.py makemigrations`
The terminal gets stuck and it doesn't show any output and even ctrl + C doesn't work

This isn't happening with all commands
commands like createsuperuser, flush, makemigrations aren't working
but commands like generateschema work

I created another django project and tried running these commands and they work.

This issue is happening with only this project and it happened suddenly.

Comment: It is hard to tell without any knowledge how your application looks like...

Comment: Can you tell me what file you would want to see?

Comment: check `manage.py shell` - if this one doesn't work it's probably something wrong in your settings.py

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl `manage.py shell` is working

Comment: so all db related commands. some changes recently in your own apps models.py? try uncommenting all custom installed apps and see if e.g. createsuperuser works again.

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl, I reverted all changes I had made and still this issue occurs,
For more info, I am using a postgres database, and I set it using a docker container I am also running my app from inside the container, and I can run these commands from inside the container shell

Answer (score 2):

You might have mistakenly changed the manage.py file or updated some libraries. If you have requirements.txt, please install everything from requirements.txt or if you have a track of the previous versions of all libraries, roll back to those versions, that might work. Thank you.

Comment: I rolledback to a previous commit where my this issue wasn't happening 
but still I am getting this issue

Comment: are you using the terminal of the framework like vs code or using the command line of windows or mac?

Comment: I have tried this in the Windows terminal and VScode

Comment: Have you activated the virtual environment while entering the command? If not make sure to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give a try to the following.

Go to `migrations` folder. There you will find files starting with `0001_initial.py` ... `0002_*****` and so on. Delete them all.

Run again the commands:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

if this doesn't work you may need to delete the database too.

> Although the Django migrations system is extremely powerful, flexible, and designed to handle large numbers of migrations, having a
> large number of model migrations causes problems when frequently
> changing your database structure (which is most often the case during
> the development phase in most cases) to most django developers, both
> beginners and even experienced. If you find yourself in this
> circumstance, there is no other option except to clean up and reset
> the migrations. But how do you go about resetting Django migrations
> when things become truly out of hand?
>
> The answer is straightforward, but it is dependent on whether you are
> still in the development phase or if you are in production, so let us
> go through the procedure step

[source](https://www.techiediaries.com/resetting-django-migrations/#How%20to%20reset%20django%20migrations)